# Can Windows Phone 7 (7.5) play RTSP stream?

Tags: windows-phone-7, rtsp, mediaelement

In this link [Supported Media Formats](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc189080), it said MediaElement object can support RTSP stream. However, when I try, it cannot. How can I play RTSP stream with MediaElement object. If MediaElement object cannot support RTSP stream. Is there any solutions can I play RTSP stream in Windows Phone? Many thanks.

Answer (score 3):

According to this [link](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/wpdevelop/thread/7a55f5ed-23cc-43ca-ac3d-567589dc4a4a/) and this [one](http://forums.create.msdn.com/forums/t/96247.aspx), posted by someone from MS, it was not supported at the time. AFAICT this has not changed.

> The Windows Phone implements a subset of Silverlight, and unfortunately it does not include RTSP.